# time difference in sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to know a difference between start time and end time. Both are DATETIME fields, I tried to use "-" and DATADIFF.

I already tried using DATADIFF and simple subtraction converting the field to just time.

1. `(to_date(Fim_Hora,'HH24:MI') - to_date(Inicio_Hora,'HH24:MI')) AS Diferenca`
2. `DATADIFF(MIN,Fim_Hora,Inicio_Hora)`

I need to know the time in minutes for use as parameters.

Comment: Oracle has no `DATETIME` data type.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Comment: Oracle does not have a "DATETIME" datatype. If you do a describe of the the table, what is the datatype of the columns fim_hora and inicio_hora ? If it is date you can just do "fim_hora - inicio_hora" - no TO_DATE needed. The result will be a date fraction: 1 = 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not have a `time` data type.  Usually, subtraction works well enough:

```
select (end_time - start_time) as diff
```

You may need to convert to a string if you want it formatted in a particular way.

Comment: the fields are DATETIME, but i need only minutes

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can directly substract dates, it returns the difference between the dates in days. To get the difference in minutes, you can multiply the result by 24 (hours per days) and 60 (minutes per hour):

```
(Fim_Hora - Inicio_Hora) * 24 * 60 diff_minutes
```

This assumes that both `Fim_Hora` and `Inicio_Hora` are of datatype `DATE`.